# CodeIgniter: custom validation rules can't be in a helper?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've created a "validation helper" that was supposed to have all my custom validation rules. The problem is that when I use them in my form validation, they seem to be ignored. If I move the functions in the controller that is doing the form validation, everything works like a charm. My validation helper is autoloaded.

Is there any reason why I can't seem to use these validation functions if I put them in a helper? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function in a helper and a controller are different obviously.

Create an [extended](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) `MY_Form_validation.php` in your `libraries/`, add the functions there and finally set the rules *without* `callback_` and just their function name.

**Example:**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    /* set_rule('custom_require') */
    function custom_require($str) {

        return (bool)$str;

    }

}
```

Comment: The file should be named `MY_Form_validation.php`, instead of `My_Form_validation.php`.  Note the capital `Y` in `MY_`.

Comment: I created a library named `validations.php` where I wrote "class Validations extends CI_Form_validation {". I wrote the rule like "trim|required|enforce_password_policy". But the thing is not working. :( Please help me out.

Comment: You probably have to name it `MY_Form_validation.php` instead of `validations.php` else CodeIgniter won't find the file.

Comment: It gives an error saying : **Unable to find validation rule: enforce_password_policy**

Comment: Sounds like a custom rule you set on your own somewhere. Create a function for it, if that's your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Robin's answer is the easiest way to deal with it; however, the *why* you can't is this:

look in your system/libraries/Form_Validation.php, line: 587

```
if ( ! method_exists($this->CI, $rule))
{
  continue;
}
```

This check is done on all callbacks. Helpers are not classes & not loaded into the CI instance - and so not available from the Form_Validation library (because of the way it is specifically coded in this method)