# I'm trying to extend the CodeIgniter Form Validation library

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, shared-libraries, codeigniter-2

This is my custom validation function.  It uses geocoding from [a Google Maps CodeIgniter library](http://in-the-attic.com/2010/08/02/codeigniter-google-maps-library-using-google-maps-api-version-3/) to check if a location exists.

```
public function address_check($str)
{
    $this->load->library('GMap');
    $this->gmap->GoogleMapAPI();

    // this method checks the cache and returns the cached response if available
    $geocodes = $this->gmap->getGeoCode("{$str}, United States");
    
    $this->form_validation->set_message('address_check', 'The %s field contains an invalid address');

    if (empty($geocodes))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

If I place the function above inside my Controller along with the following rule, it works perfectly well.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'callback_address_check');
```

---

Now I simply want to move it out of my Controller.  So I'm trying to extend my CodeIgniter Form Validation library as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652934/594235) and [the CI documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

I created a file here:  `/codeigniter/application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function address_check($str)
    {
        $this->load->library('GMap');
        $this->gmap->GoogleMapAPI();

        // this method checks the cache and returns the cached response if available
        $geocodes = $this->gmap->getGeoCode("{$str}, United States");

        $this->form_validation->set_message('address_check', 'The %s field contains an invalid address');
        
        if (empty($geocodes))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

}
```

And from within my controller, I am setting the rule like this...

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'address_check');
```

The first problem I found and solved myself was that nothing was happening because [that SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652934/594235) incorrectly specified the file name to be `My_Form_validation.php` where it should have been `MY_Form_validation.php`

Now that the function is being called, the new problem is that I am getting the following error:

> Message: Undefined property: MY_Form_validation::$load
>
> Filename: libraries/MY_Form_validation.php
>
> Line Number: 12

This is line 12:

```
$this->load->library('GMap');
```

I can't access a library from within a library?  What's the proper way to fix this?  I'd prefer not to auto-load the GMap library since I won't be using it all the time.  Any other problems within my method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('GMap');
```

And then use it like:

```
$CI->gmap->GoogleMapAPI();
```

You have to do it that way, because Form Validation is not like CI Model or Controller class, it's only library.

Comment: That fixed the errors, but now there is no validation at all.  I also changed this line to:  `$geocodes = $CI->gmap->getGeoCode("{$str}, United States");`

Comment: You tried to return `FALSE` at the very beginning of function and check if validation is failing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but as a test I moved `return FALSE` outside of the conditional and the validation message works.  The failure is that `$geocodes` is never `empty`, even when it should be.  I guess something is wrong with `$geocodes = $CI->gmap->getGeoCode("{$str}, United States");`

Comment: You could also check if `"{$str}, United States"` is what you want it to be.

Comment: Yeah, `$str` is correct, but something is very wrong with `$geocodes`.  Yesterday, it was empty on invalid address (random characters).  However, today it's returning Lat & Lon on everything... it's the same problem even when I moved it back into the Controller.  I guess I'll need to find a better method to validate an address.

Comment: Thank-you for solving my problem.  Apparently, the results returned back from Google is not what I expect.  [This is somebody else's validator](http://www.thialfi.org/work/api/validate.html) which says addresses such as `w` and `q` are valid.  My code is working fine.

Comment: No problem. Maybe you could parse your string through GMap library, and then check if country is United States. And maybe first valid it with regex or something.

Comment: I put back `"United States"`, but I might have to parse my input further to check for number of commas or something.

Answer (score 3):

Inside of your library, you can extend other models, libraries, configs, helpers, etc... by first loading the CI class.  For example, in your constructor you can accomplish this through the following:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->ci =& get_instance();
}
```

Once you have loaded the CI class, you can load any other classes that may need loading.

Examples:

```
$this->ci->load->library("session");
$this->ci->load->model("my_model");
$this->ci->load->helper("file");
```

Or in your case:

```
$this->ci->load->library("GMap");
```

You can then call functions from the class in a similar fashion throughout your class:

```
$this->ci->gmap->GoogleMapAPI();
$this->ci->gmap->getGeoCode("{$str}, United States");
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem as being discussed on the other answer.  This clears all of my errors but `$this->ci->gmap->getGeoCode("{$str}, United States");` is never empty.  And if it's never empty, it's always passing validation.  This exact same function is working properly when it's placed in my Controller.

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump($str)` and `var_dump($geocodes)` to see that their values are being set properly?

Comment: Yeah, `$str` is correct, but `$geocodes` is always returning a lat/lon location even when junk is passed into it.  I'll have to find a better way to validate addresses.  Weirdly, this was working fine inside my Controller yesterday.  Today, it's not working no matter where I put it.

Comment: Even when `United States` is removed and just `$str=w`, `getGeoCode("$str")` gives a lat/lon location returned to me.  ?!

Comment: FYI ->  playing with a Google Maps validator, I guess `w` is a valid address according to this:  http://www.thialfi.org/work/api/validate.html

Comment: Looking at the GoogleMapAPI class you are using (https://github.com/gkwelding/GoogleMapsV3CI/blob/master/GMap.php), it appears that `getGeoCode()` is indeed supposed to return a latitude and longitude set of coordinates.

Comment: True, but only if it's a valid address.  [Looking at this demo](http://www.thialfi.org/work/api/validate.html), the results here are matching my validation results one for one.  So a `w` is a valid address after all, but `gwwwww` is not.  The problem is not my code.