# Helper function not working properly in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I have created a helper function call the function each file. Basically the function is checking if the uploaded file is pdf/xlsx, but the function not returning anything as  result. I could not figure it out where is the error.

My controller

```
class Bike_insurance_brochure extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        if(!is_admin_logged_in())
            redirect("/admin","refresh",301);

        $this->load->model('admin/bike_insurance_brochure_m');
    }

    function index(){
        $this->load->admin_template('bike_insurance_brochure_view');
    }

    function save(){
        $config=array(
            array(
                'field'=>'product_b',
                'label'=>'Product Brochure',
                'rules'=>'trim|callback_check_brochure'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'product_w',
                'label'=>'Policy Wordings',
                'rules'=>'trim|callback_check_word'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'product_c',
                'label'=>'Policy Claim',
                'rules'=>'trim|callback_check_claim'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'company',
                'label'=>'company',
                'rules'=>'trim|max_length[255]'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'product',
                'label'=>'product',
                'rules'=>'trim|required'
            )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run()!==FALSE){
            print_r(json_encode($this->bike_insurance_brochure_m->save()));
        }
        else{
            $error= "<ul>";
            $error.= validation_errors("<li>", "</li>");
            $error.= "</ul>";
            print_r(json_encode(['status'=>'false','message'=>$error]));
        }
    }

    function get_product_details($bike_insu_bro_id=NULL){
        if($bike_insu_bro_id==NULL || trim($bike_insu_bro_id)==""){
            print_r(json_encode(['status'=>'false','message'=>'Invalid record selected']));
        }

        print_r(json_encode($this->bike_insurance_brochure_m->get_product_details($bike_insu_bro_id)));

    }

    function update_details($bike_insu_bro_id){
        $config=array(
            array(
                'field'=>'product_b',
                'label'=>'Product Brochure',
                'rules'=>'trim|callback_check_brochure'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'product_w',
                'label'=>'Policy Wordings',
                'rules'=>'trim|callback_check_word'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'product_c',
                'label'=>'Policy Claim',
                'rules'=>'trim|callback_check_claim'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'company',
                'label'=>'company',
                'rules'=>'trim|max_length[255]'
            ),
            array(
                'field'=>'product',
                'label'=>'product',
                'rules'=>'trim|required'
            )
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run()!==FALSE){
            print_r(json_encode($this->bike_insurance_brochure_m->update_details($bike_insu_bro_id)));
        }
        else{
            $error= "<ul>";
            $error.= validation_errors("<li>", "</li>");
            $error.= "</ul>";
            print_r(json_encode(['status'=>'false','message'=>$error]));
        }
    }

    function delete($bike_insu_bro_id=NULL){
        if($bike_insu_bro_id==NULL || trim($bike_insu_bro_id)==""){
            print_r(json_encode(['status'=>'false','message'=>'Invalid record selected']));
        }
        print_r(json_encode($this->bike_insurance_brochure_m->delete($bike_insu_bro_id)));
    }

    function get_bike_insurance_brochure_list($page=1){
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('paginationlib');
        try
        {
            $pagingConfig = $this->paginationlib->initPagination($this->bike_insurance_brochure_m->record_count());
            $list = $this->bike_insurance_brochure_m->get_bike_insurance_brochure_list((($page-1) * $pagingConfig['per_page']),$pagingConfig['per_page']);
            $list["pagination"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $list['index_start']=(50*($page-1))+1;
            print_r($this->load->view('admin/ajax/bike_insurance_brochure_list',$list,TRUE));
        }
        catch (Exception $err){}
    }
    function get_bike_product_list(){
        print_r(json_encode($this->bike_insurance_brochure_m->get_product_list($this->input->post('company'))));
    }

function check_brochure(){
   check_brochure($this->input->post('product_b'));
  }
function check_word(){
   check_word($this->input->post('product_w'));
  }
function check_claim(){
    check_claim($this->input->post('product_c'));
  }


}
```

custom helper function

```
if (!function_exists('check_brochure'))
{
   function check_brochure($product_brochure){
    $CI =& get_instance();

        $allowed_mime_type_arr = array("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document","application/pdf","application/msword");
        $mime_brochure = get_mime_by_extension($product_brochure);
        if(isset($product_brochure) && $product_brochure !=""){
            if(in_array($mime_brochure, $allowed_mime_type_arr)){
                echo 'hi';
                return true;
            }else{
                $CI->form_validation->set_message('check_brochure', 'Please select only .pdf/.docx/.doc Product Brochure.');
                echo 'ye';
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            $CI->form_validation->set_message('check_brochure', 'Please choose a file to upload Product Brochure.');
             echo 'bye';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It is returning bye while checking but function is not return to false, I mean error message not showing. My autoload.php:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file','form','email_settings','comm_func','html','string','globals');
```

Comment: Just some out of the box thinking... If you're using CI's upload functionality, wouldn't it just be easier to use that functionality to not allow anything other than PDF or XLSX files?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can use callback in form validation from same class. So define your helper function as a method in `Bike_insurance_brochure` class. After that you can use as callback.

But If want to make a library there are a another way to do it. You can extend native `CI_Form_validation` library and define method there.

details [CodeIgniter: custom validation rules can't be in a helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652870/codeigniter-custom-validation-rules-cant-be-in-a-helper)

Also try without `isset()` function

```
if($product_brochure && $product_brochure !=""){
 //....
```

Comment: I think i have done that ##efine your helper function as a method in Bike_insurance_brochure class. After that you can use as callback.


function check_brochure(){
   check_brochure($this->input->post('product_b'));
  }
function check_word(){
   check_word($this->input->post('product_w'));
  }
function check_claim(){
    check_claim($this->input->post('product_c'));
  }

Comment: @Swagatika I have updated answer, now check without `isset`

Comment: i have also check without isset , but same issue
Any how i have resolved it ,as i have forgotton to add return while calling helper function .

Answer (score 0):

For uploads, you won't get the `form_validation` to work, as it'll only work for regular form fields (anything accessible through `$this->input->post("field_name")`). For anything regarding the files uploaded through the form, which you'd access through `$this->upload->data()`, you need to work with the configuration of the upload library.

On Codeigniter, all multipart forms work this way. I usually simplify my workflow by doing:

```
$data = array(
    'upload_data'   => $this->upload->data(),
    'form_data'     => $this->input->post(),
);
```

So I access everything as `$data['form_data']['field_name']` and `$data['upload_data']['upload_parameter']` (`upload_parameter` being one of many things CI does automagically for you)

Try this example... it's just a quick type, you may improve it a lot:
(in my example, the file field is called 'userfile')

```
// define your settings
$config['upload_path'] = wherever/you/need/the/file/to/end/up;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|xls|xlsx';

// initialize the upload library
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

// do_upload actually uploads the file and checks that the configuration settings you defined are met
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
print "<pre>".print_r($error,true)."</pre>";
```

try doing this and you'll get it to work (and not need the use of a helper function, as the built-in CI functionality already handles almost everything for you)